# Serenity BDD course or start up guide

Tags: java, cucumber, serenity-bdd

this is my first question. I would like to learn about Serenity BDD with screenplay. Can anyone suggest a good online course/videos/tutorial to learn more about it.

Comment: The author has already written good documentation here: https://serenity-bdd.github.io/theserenitybook/latest/index.html You should start with it.

Comment: Thanks @TimothyT.

Answer (score 1):

you should to refer here http://serenitydojo.teachable.com/. This is online training course that is provided by John Smart person who created Serenity BDD Framework.

Comment: Thanks @ngộ-thiện-phương